How To Implement this Marked part in flutter?

I am learning flutter for couple of months and i am struggling in this type of ui design. Can you body help me to implement this kind of design?
I have tried using stack but it is not working.
How can i float a container in a container?

In your design what is the prblm specifically. Your design contains lots of elements. In which part do you need help and what is the prblm. If it's the curve for bg can't your create it using border radius or atmost use custom paint

It's a broad question. Which part are you struggling with? Try to post some of the code that you started with, and mention how do you need help...

Thank you for you response! I struggling with the horizontal list view part! The red marked area! More over i am struggling to position it properly.  The white shape containers are positioned in the both area(white and blue).

wihtout us telling what you have tried and also show the code piece that should build that part it is hard to help.

Try stack like below in your code. Give container's height as your need.
 Stack(alignment: Alignment.topCenter, children: [
      Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        color: Colors.pinkAccent,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.5,
            color: Colors.orange,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.5),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6.5,
        child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: 5,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(50), topLeft: Radius.circular(5))),
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                ),
              );
            }),
      ),
    ])


Instead of just posting a code snippet it would be better to explain the concept behind it.

Do I have to use the stack for the hole scaffold body???

Yes, you can use stack for the whole scaffold body, and your another bottom widgets are in 1st container. Wrap Align with Column / Row as your requirement.

Thank You for your guidance. I have  successed

@MirajHossainShawon, If you found a solution from an answer, accept the answer so that others can easily find a solution to the same problem.
